# MEF getting exports with a string

Tags: c#, mef

Is it possible to get exports by only have a string?  The parts are in the container but I only have a string to resolve the correct part.  MEF seems to want types to resolve, and things like Type.GetType() require a hard reference.  Can't use a generic interface, need very specific parts.

The string can be changed to match what ever is needed.  (I think)

```
container.GetExports("ClassLibrary1.Class1")
```

I haven't played with the metadata stuff but can you resolve based on a metadata string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get parts without a reference to the type, what are you hoping to accomplish with the part once you have it? Also note that you can reference a type without an object using [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) or by using generic methods.

This is why MEF is usually wired up using public interfaces, rather than concrete and/or nonpublic types.

What you're looking for is the default Contract Name for a given type, however any helper methods for looking up that default name will require the `Type` object and fall under the same explanation as above.

EDIT: The above applies if you're trying to find the contract name for a given class. For differentiating exports of the same type, see below

When exporting, you can [specify both a contract name and export type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833299(v=vs.110).aspx), such as

```
[Export("Contract", typeof(IInterface))]
public class Part : IInterface { /*...*/ }
```

This can allow you to differentiate between multiple parts. If you want the part imported as part of an `ImportMany` directive, you must *also* export it without a contract name, such as

```
[Export("Contract", typeof(IInterface))]
[Export(typeof(IInterface))]
public class Part : IInterface { /*...*/ }
```

Since attributes are allowed to take `const` values, it may also be useful to specify the individual contract names in a collection of names, IE

```
public static class ContractNames
{
    public const string Contract = "Contract";
}

[Export(ContractNames.Contract, typeof(IInterface))]
[Export(typeof(IInterface))]
public class Part : IInterface { /*...*/ }

...
    container.GetExportedValue<IInterface>(ContractNames.Contract);
```

Note the above uses [`GetExportedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986499(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `GetExports` since the former will directly compose and return values, instead of export metadata

Comment: They all inherit from a simple interface so that the system can run them, but I have to find the one correct part at runtime on the fly with a string.  It's looking like I will  have to investigate the metadata aspects of mef.

Comment: not able to resolve with getexportedvalue even though i can see in the container.  Error: No exports were found that match the constraint: \n\tContractName\tClassLibrary1.Class1\n\tRequiredTypeIdentity\tClassLibrary3.IInterface" but the parts [0] = {[ExportTypeIdentity, ClassLibrary2.Class2]}

Comment: odd.  I  change the string contract export to "abc" and its still classlibrary1.class1 in the container's export def.

Comment: or the interface depending on how export is used, but never the string.